# D3: Set background colour for a chart

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm working on a visualisation involving stacked histogram with really thin bars.

The problem is that white background introduces unpleasant visual vibration and make bars somewhat hard to interpret:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN0XD.png

What I'm looking for is a way to set a specific colour for chart background. I've tried to set it for SVG element like so:

```
svg {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

But (obviously) it doesn't work properly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctbYo.png

How do I set a background colour so that it'll be exactly the same shape as a chart?

Comment: Please note that `background-color` is not an attribute applicable to `<svg>`. Although it might work for some user agents it will most likely break in others. To get further help you need to provide some more details/code on how you are constructing the svg using d3.js.

Comment: It looks like it's applying the background-color, as desired, it's just doing it with extra margins on the left and bottom.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @altocumulus. The code pretty much resembles [this sample by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208). Except that I don't use an X scale, and rects widths are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come to this quick-and-dirty solution. Just adding a one pixel pseudo-shadow to the right of each bar:

```
rect {
  -webkit-svg-shadow: 1px 0px #ccc;
}
```

Produces this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSVOD.png

Answer (score -1):

How is the chart being instantiated? by using svg { background-color: #ccc;} you are setting the background color of all svg elements to #ccc (except where over-ridden), so if your chart is a child of another svg element with some margins it would explain why the alignment is no good.

One strategy to go about fixing may be to use your browser's debugging abilities (ctrl+shift+i to bring up 'developer tools' in chrome) to take a look at the DOM elements and try to narrow down which ones cover which areas of the graph vs the areas of the graph plus the margins on the bottom/left. not sure about other browsers but chrome is useful in that if you hover over an element in the html document it will 'highlight' that element in the browser. This might help you  narrow down which objects specifically need to be stylized.